# Autoplot prcomp with percentage

Tags: r, ggfortify

I want to include the percentage for `PC1` and `PC2` on my plot, is that possible to do directly using autoplot?

```
plotPCA <- autoplot(prcomp(df),data=b, colour="labs")
```

Comment: you have `Standard deviations` and `Rotation` outputs from `prcomp`. which one are you trying to plot?

Comment: We also have Proportion of Variance, which is what I want

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
data("iris")
PCA = prcomp(iris[-5])
dfdf = stats:::summary.prcomp(PCA)$importance[2, ]
plotPCA <- autoplot(ts(dfdf))
plotPCA
```